How to achieve stable lane-following for a large non-holonomic vehicle in Nav2 without late path adherence?
I am working with a large, non-holonomic robot (a truck-sized vehicle, approximately 12 meters long by 5 meters wide) using ROS2 Navigation2 (Nav2). My goal is to have it follow lane-like paths smoothly and anticipate turns well before obstacles, similar to a lane-keeping assist system. Currently, it tends to either drive straight too long and only turn sharply at the last moment or oscillate in its trajectory planning.
What I’ve tried so far:
1- Behavior Trees & Replanning Strategy:
I’ve experimented with different behavior trees and replanning conditions. For example, using:
navigate_through_poses:
  default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_only_if_path_becomes_invalid.xml"

This is to avoid infinite replanning loops. However, the vehicle still postpones path adherence until late.
2-MPPI Controller with Fine-Tuned Parameters:
Using nav2_mppi_controller, I heavily tuned parameters for a large Ackermann-type vehicle. I increased the planning horizon, adjusted vx_std and wz_std, set a larger prune distance, and scaled up the PathFollow and PathAlign critic weights. Despite this, the vehicle still often goes straight and only tries to join the required path curvature at the last second.

Example snippet:
FollowPath:
  plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
  time_steps: 60
  model_dt: 0.05
  vx_max: 5.0
  wz_max: 3.0
  iteration_count: 15
  temperature: 0.02
  gamma: 0.02
  prune_distance: 30.0
  max_robot_pose_search_dist: 10.0
  # Critics adjusted with high penalties to stick to the path

3-Regulated Pure Pursuit Controller Attempts: I switched to the nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller. I tried larger lookahead distances (up to 10m), velocity-scaled lookahead, cost and curvature regulation, and removed rotate-in-place behaviors since the truck is non-holonomic. Despite these adjustments, it still delays starting its turn and adheres to the path too late.
4-Obstacle & Lane Costmaps (Virtual Lane Concept): I created a script that assigns a “virtual lane” by marking areas outside the lane as lethal (red zones) and inside as permissible (green zones). This restricts the planner to a lane-like corridor. However, because the lethal zones come from point cloud data, there are small gaps (no perfect continuous barrier), and the planner still sometimes tries to slip through these tiny gaps or delay the turn:


I would like to definitely avoid this.
I also implemented logic where if the current lane is blocked, I:

Cancel the current NavigateThroughPoses goal,
Brake the truck (publish zero velocities for a period),
Compute a new route on a lateral lane (a set of waypoints
representing an alternate path),
Then send a new NavigateThroughPoses goal to follow that lateral lane
until the current lane is clear again.

This theoretically should push the truck to deviate earlier, but in practice it still does so at the last possible moment or exhibits oscillatory behavior.
Video Links:
(A) Single waypoint goal (no virtual lanes): https://youtu.be/0kYenYx9arA
This shows the truck oscillating when no virtual roadway is used. I tried fine-tuning the planner and controller for large, non-holonomic vehicles, but it still wobbles before reaching the final pose.
(B) MPPI with multiple waypoints (no virtual lanes): https://youtu.be/5hKgWlGxuE0
Using several waypoints causes the truck to eventually collide with an obstacle. Without the virtual lane, it attempts to follow a line of waypoints but doesn’t deviate in time.
(C) Virtual lane scenario (with lane costs and alternate paths): https://youtu.be/HWlf-6Hv3PY
The truck now has a virtual lane and alternate routes available. However, it still delays adhering to the alternate route, aiming straight ahead until it’s too late, leading to collisions or getting stuck.
Goal: I need the vehicle to follow the lane center smoothly, anticipating turns and not deferring steering corrections until it’s too late. Essentially, I’m looking for a way to achieve more stable, earlier path adherence—no last-second course corrections and fewer oscillations. It should behave more like a lane-keeping system in an autonomous driving scenario.

Are there recommended parameter adjustments or known best practices
for large, non-holonomic robots using MPPI or Regulated Pure Pursuit
to achieve earlier, more stable path adherence?
Would switching from SmacPlanner with Dubin curves to Reeds-Shepp or
another planner help with earlier path corrections?
Is there a known workaround to ensure the truck recognizes and
compensates for upcoming curves well in advance, maybe through
different critics or costmap configurations?
Is my approach of assigning lethal costs outside the lane and masks
for obstacle/occupancy too simplistic or is there a better method to
strongly enforce lane-center following? I tried to emulate the keep-out zone from tutorial, which requires a previous map to create a prohibited zone.

I am also facing a harsh fine-tuning to reach an acceptable trajectory path to curvy paths using SMAC+MPPI:
Techniques and tools for fine-tuning Navigation2 planners (Smac, MPPI) to reduce erratic behavior on curved paths
If someone has expertise with this kind of tuning, hints are very welcome:
Any insights from others who have tackled large vehicle lane-following with Nav2 would be greatly appreciated.
